# added Google API key still getting error API key not found

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I did add google API key in meta data in my manifest file but still getting error "API key not found"

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.abit">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
  >   
 <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
  <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.geo.AIzaSyDPUc0RSV5OZzACrJcFPuBpxUHi0000000"
android:value="AIzaSyDPUc0RSV5OZzACrJcFPuBpxUHi0000000" />
</application>
```

I don't know where it is going wrong.
Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/apikey/maps-android-apikey#add-key,) steps, you should add  tag as a a child of application tag, the meta data should look like:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```

So, as per this your code should be:

```
<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
 >   
  <activity
     android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
   android:launchMode="singleTask"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
 </activity>
 <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
 <meta-data android:name="android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY""
  android:value="AIzaSyDPUc0RSV5OZzACrJcFPuBpxUHi0000000" />
 </application>
```

**Point to Note:** You are passing the value for `android:name` as `com.google.android.geo.AIzaSyDPUc0RSV5OZzACrJcFPuBpxUHi0000000` instead of `com.google.android.geo.API_KEY`

Comment: Thanks it works. I thought it is for API key.

Comment: Yes, the language can be confusing at times :D